How is the emf in a transformer related to voltage of power supply?
As far as I've learnt, the emf of the primary coil in a transformer is induced due to a change in current in the coil by the AC power supply. This change drives a change in the solenoid's magnetic field, leads to a change in magnetic flux and, thus, induces an emf in the primary coil. The rate of change of magnetic flux is given by:
$$\frac{d\phi_B}{dt} = \frac{\mu_0AN_p^2}{s}\frac{dI}{dt} = V_p.$$
The emf across the primary coil, therefore, should have nothing to do with the voltage of the AC power supply. It should only depend on the geometry of the primary coil, the number of turns and the rate of change of the current. But the following question is asked in my Physics textbook which perplexes me:

A transformer has 500 turns in its primary coil and 20,000 turns in its secondary coil. An AC voltage with maximum voltage of 100 V is applied to the primary coil. What is the maximum voltage across the secondary coil?

The solution is:
$$\frac{V_s}{V_p} = \frac{N_s}{N_p}\implies V_s = 100\cdot\frac{20000}{500} = 4000 V$$
How does the maximum AC voltage have anything to do with the maximum voltage in the primary coil?

The 100 V AC is applied to the primary.  - I'm not sure what you're asking.

@M.Enns doesn't $V_p$ represent the emf that is self induced by the solenoid? By the equation I gave, this only depends on the rate of the change of the current through the coil (and the solenoid's properties). How is this related to the AC supply?

To put it a little crudely the first equation is finding the induced voltage of the secondary from a known magnetic field strength and rate of change. The question as asked by the textbook is asking for the secondary voltage with a given turn ratio and known input voltage. Is that the source of confusion?


It should only depend on the geometry of the primary coil, the number of turns and the rate of change of the current … How does the maximum AC voltage have anything to do with the maximum voltage in the primary coil?

The power supply provides both voltage and current. The primary characteristic of an ideal voltage source is that it supplies whatever current is necessary to achieve the specified voltage.
So, as you said, the voltage depends on the rate of change of the current. So the power supply can achieve the specified voltage by providing a current which changes at the necessary rate.

I guess more specifically, I wanted to know how the maximum emf induced in primary coil = maximum voltage of AC supply?

@Aryaan my answer applies to all voltages of the power supply, including the maximum
